# How to access storage.get object value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to store data in localStorage and then access it by key, use the value of such key and set it as a variable to be able to work with it further.

When I run the code below the console prints: 'result exists [object Object]'.

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var keyVar = 'key Var Value';
var obj= {};
obj[keyVar] = 'value Value';

storage.set(obj);
storage.get(keyVar,function(result){
    if (isEmpty(result)) {
        console.log("result does not exist");
    }
    else {
        console.log("result exists " + result);
    }
});

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I check the local storage using

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})
```

It correctly logs the object: '{key Var Value: "value Value"}'

I need to store the value into a variable to be then passed into a function. In the couple of hours googling I wasn't able to achieve that.
I tried these but all return undefined.

```
console.log("result exists " + result.keyVar);
console.log("result exists " + keyVar.result);
```

Comment: `console.log("result exists " + result[keyVar]);`

Comment: Oh my god, thank you Iván! I was getting desperate there for a moment.

Comment: 1) Use `,` instead of `+` in your console.log and you'll see an object properly. 2) Extension storage is **not** localStorage which is the standard HTML5 localStorage - don't let the official documentation for Chrome extension confuse you.